# Manage users in my Windows application Logic without having Active Directory

Tags: c#, sql-server, business-logic

What is the good way to manage users in my Windows application based on SQL Server database without Active Directory? Should I manage users in SQL Server or in the C# application, because I don't have Active Directory ?

Comment: i can't underestand your question compeletly. if you want make a user managment in windows application you can see below link. if not please describe your problem any more https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/556872/userplusrolesplusmanagementplusinplusc-23pluswindo

Comment: In similar post @Cj S. asked that : Manage your users and their roles in active directory. Perform authentication and authorization in your app (using, for example, membership and role providers). But in my case, i haven't active directory and a have a windows c# application used with sql server Database, and all users should not have full access to all part of application. I have 3 groups (Administrator that acces to all part of application, Admin idem of Administrator with some restrictions and User that have limited acces in UI)

Comment: Thanks @Hadi, according above link and after many search, i have found solution. And i've posted a related repository at github.com/josamuna/MembershipFrameworkSample could be help anyone that have the same issue.

Comment: @Jo7 why use that at all? The OS knows who the logged in user is already. You *don't* need anything extra. Using "Active Directory" means using Windows accounts and nothing more. Even if the customer uses machines that joined in a domain (really? no servers at all in the entire company?), Windows Authentication works in workgroup environments too

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, i thinks that is true but, but the main issue in my case is that i haven't Active Directory configured. Unless I misunderstood your answer?